# Problem calling a function in a remote spatial database in which a transform function is used

Tags: oracle, function, package, spatial, dblink

I need to retrieve the coordinates (x,y) in a "spatial" database from a "classic" database through dblink.

here is my Oracle version:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

the dblink between the 2 database works fine.

I have created a Function in the Spatial database which get the SGO_GEOMETRY of an object and return the sdo_point.x
=> that workd fine through dblink

Now I need to transform the current x in another spatial unit.
to do that, I use

> MDSYS.SDO_CS.transform

It works fine if a run the function in the Spatial database.
It crashes if I call the function through dblink.

here is my function in the spatial database:

```
FUNCTION TEST_GEOMETRY
    (
        p_compteur E_COMPTEUR_ABONNE.numero_reel%type
    ) 
    return number is
        w_geometry MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY;
        w_geometry_transformed MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY;
    begin
        begin
            select geometry into w_geometry from E_COMPTEUR_ABONNE where numero_reel = p_compteur;
            EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found then return null; -- Compteur non trouvée 
        end;

        return w_geometry.sdo_point.x;

    end TEST_GEOMETRY;
```

if I run it from the "none spatial" database it works fine:

`select  test.test_geometry@elyx('09P010650') from dual;`

result:1711071,438

Now, I replace 
`return w_geometry.sdo_point.x;`

by

```
   w_geometry_transformed :=MDSYS.SDO_CS.transform(w_geometry,4326);
   return w_geometry_transformed.sdo_point.x;
```

it works fine if I run it in the spatial database.
I've got this through DBLINK:

> Your database connection has been reset. Any pending transactions or sesseion state has been lost.

At first, I thought it was some kind of authorization missing on my DBLINK user, but MDSYS is PUBLIC.
So I have try another function from the package MDSYS.SOD_CS and it works:

> w_test := MDSYS.SDO_CS.tfm_axis_orientation_to_wkt('test');
>           return 1;

only functions using a MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY parameters seemed to failed.

Do you have an idea why and what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly good at Oracle Spatial, but I know that SDO_GEOMETRY just won't work over a database link.

Fortunately, there are some workarounds, one of them being WKT (Well Know Text) which represents geometry as *text*. There are two function you can use:

- SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY
- SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY

so - see if these could help.

For some more reading, have a look at Alex Paterson's blog, describing what else you could do (http://www.tolon.co.uk/2012/09/geometry-objects-across-dblink/).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I understand that you can't use Spatial objet through dblink and there are those workarounds that you propose. But in my case, i let the spatial database do the job. I only retrieve numbers (x or y)  through the dblink. i can do "return w_geometry.sdo_point.x;". So i use a spacial data.

Comment: You're welcome. If I understood you correctly, you managed to solve the problem. If so, I'm glad you did.